# How to filter object attributes with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a array of categories object

```
categoriesTree : [
    {name: 'cat1', id:1, selected : true},
    {name: 'cat2', id:2, selected : false},
    {name: 'cat3', id:3, selected : true},
    {name: 'cat4', id:4, selected : false},
    {name: 'cat6', id:6, selected : true},
]
```

To get the selected categories I did:

```
selectedCategories = filterFilter($scope.categoriesTree, {selected:true})
```

this will give me:

```
categoriesTree : [
    {name: 'cat1', id:1, selected : true},
    {name: 'cat3', id:3, selected : true},
    {name: 'cat6', id:6, selected : true},
]
```

But to reduce the POST data to send, I just want the id attribue so I want an array like this:

```
['1', '3', '6']
```

Is that possible to do with AngularJS filters ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res = categoriesTree.map(function(el) { return el.id; });
```

Short and simple, with the good ole js.

To answer your question: no, with filters you can't, but it is possible with [forEach](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom angularjs filter that not only "filters" but also "projects" your set into a different set.  I think you can definitely project each category object into just its ID.

See [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) for an example of how to create a custom filter in angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use underscorejs's `_.pluck` method.

```
selectedCategories = _.pluck(_.filter(categoriesTree, function(category) {
    return category.selected;
}), 'id');
```

which returns an array of the values of all the `id`'s where the corresponding `selected` value is `true`.